# Send email with custom fields after new draft is saved or new post published

Tags: custom-field, hooks, post-status, customization

I have a custom post type `immobile` with some custom fields created with Toolset Types.

I need to send and email with the title and a custom field when a new `immobile` is saved as a draft or it's published.

I managed to do **almost** everthing. My code is like this:

```
add_action( 'auto-draft_to_draft', 'my_send_email', 99 );
add_action( 'auto-draft_to_publish', 'my_send_email', 99 );
add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'my_send_email', 99 );
function my_send_email( $post ) {
  if ( $post->post_type == 'immobile' ) {
    wp_mail(
      'email@example.com',
      'New immobile saved as ' . $post->post_status,
      'Title: ' . $post->post_title . '. Ref: ' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'wpcf-reference', true ),
      array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8')
    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately my custom field is not showing in the email, probably because It get saved after the hook I'm using.

The perfect solution would be a hook wich:

1. Is fired **after** the post meta are saved
2. Allow me to check the *post_status* of the post **before** it was saved.

I tried the hook `post updated` but I got the same result: the custom field does not show up.

Which hook could I use? Or I should try a totally different approach?

Comment: Not familiar with toolset , it might be because it saves the value after post is published . Does it have separate action like acf/save_post  ?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: @AnoopD unfortunately their documentation says "Types does not have a proper hooks API". However, this applies to all custom fields, not only the ones created with Toolset

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle post request first.
You have to do this because gutenberg calls the hook twice.

```
function transition_post_status_handler( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST ) {
        send_mail_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post );
        set_transient( 'post_status_updater_flag', 'done', 10 );
    } else {
        if ( false === get_transient( 'post_status_updater_flag' ) )
            send_mail_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post );
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'transition_post_status_handler', 10, 3 );
```

Then you can call the function to send the email.
At this point I think you have the data of the meta available.

```
function send_mail_on_publish( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    if ( 'publish' == $new_status && 'immobile' == get_post_type($post) ) {

        // Check if not an autosave
        if ( wp_is_post_autosave( $post->ID ) )
            return;

        // Check if not a revision
        if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post->ID ) )
            return;

        // Send email

    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment my client doesn't want to use Gutenberg and it's sticking to the classic editor. I'll give it a try outside her working hours. If it works as expected, this could be the reason for her to finally switch to Gutenberg

Comment: I haven't tested the script on the classic editor but I think it works with him too. You just have to test it.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't send any email. I tried removing the `if ( defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) ...` and I get 10 emails in my inbox! 8 without custom field, 2 with it. This gives me hope for Gutenberg

Comment: I just changed the `transition_post_status_handler` function try now

Comment: I tried with Gutenberg and the result is similar: 7 emails instead of 10, 2 with the custom field. But I think you function is a good base to work with, I just need some time to do some more testing.